# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 coming only on device

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, linker-errors, xcode7

When i'm trying to test my app on device i get the below error. The error is not coming in simulator. I'm using xcode 7. Can someone please help?

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1",
>   referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_cipher_ctx_key_derive in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_HMAC_CTX_init", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_HMAC_Init_ex", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_HMAC_Final", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_HMAC_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_RAND_bytes", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_init in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_HMAC_Update", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CipherInit", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CipherFinal", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_get_cipherbyname", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)
>         _sqlcipher_activate in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_activate in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_MD_size", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_sha1", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)
>         _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CIPHER_key_length", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CipherUpdate", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CIPHER_iv_length", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o)   "_EVP_CIPHER_block_size", referenced from:
>         _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlcipher.a(sqlite3.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: is the device is updated to iOS 9.0

Comment: Yes the device is updated to iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0):

The common causes for "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" are:

1. You import a header and do not link against the correct library. This is common, especially for headers for libraries like QuartzCore since it is not included in projects by default. To resolve:

   - Add the correct libraries in the Link Binary With Libraries section    of the Build Phases.
   - If you want to add a library outside of the default search path you can include the path in the Library Search Paths value in the Build Settings and add `-l{library_name_without_lib_and_suffix}` (eg. for libz.a use -lz) to the Other Linker Flags section of Build Settings.
2. You copy files into your project but forgot to check the target to add the files to. To resolve:

   - Open the Build Phases for the correct target, expand Compile Sources and add the missing .m files.

You include a static library that is built for another architecture like i386, the simulator on your host machine. To resolve:

If you have multiple library files from your libraries vendor to include in the project you need to include the one for the simulator (i386) and the one for the device (armv7 for example).

Answer (score 0):

These are OpenSSL symbols, so you are probably not linking against libcrypto. Add -lcrypto to the linker flags.

Comment: I have added -lcrypto to the linker flags but still i get the same error.