# Linker fails to link openssl headers when building mysql-connector-c++ example

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, linker, mysql-connector

I am trying to build an application that uses the mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.13.

The problem that I am having is that the linker seems to fail to link/find some headers but I have no idea why. I have looked through the [mysql-connector-c++1 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html), multiple stackoverflow and github posts/threads but couldnt find anything that helped.

The error I am getting is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_CIPHER_block_size", referenced from:
      my_aes_get_size(unsigned int, my_aes_opmode) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(my_aes_openssl.cc.o)
  "_EVP_CIPHER_iv_length", referenced from:
      my_aes_encrypt(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, my_aes_opmode, unsigned char const*, bool) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(my_aes_openssl.cc.o)
      my_aes_decrypt(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, my_aes_opmode, unsigned char const*, bool) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(my_aes_openssl.cc.o)
      my_aes_needs_iv(my_aes_opmode) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(my_aes_openssl.cc.o)
  "_FIPS_mode", referenced from:
      set_fips_mode(unsigned int, char*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(viosslfactories.cc.o)
      get_fips_mode() in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(viosslfactories.cc.o)
  "_FIPS_mode_set", referenced from:
      set_fips_mode(unsigned int, char*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(viosslfactories.cc.o)
  "_SSL_get_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      ssl_verify_server_cert(Vio*, char const*, char const**) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(client.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As I understand this means that the the program couldnt link some headers found in the openSSL library, even though I am linking openSSL in my CMakeLists.txt here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

set(PROJECT_NAME "ChatBot")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(PROJECT_PATH /myPath)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanBuild/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanBuild/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    conan_basic_setup()
else()
    message(WARNING "The file conanbuildinfo.cmake doesn't exist, you have to run ./build.sh first")
endif()

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_PATH}/mysql-connector/include
    ${PROJECT_PATH}/mysql-connector/include/cppconn
)

link_directories(mysql-connector/lib)

add_library(libmysqlcppconn STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libmysqlcppconn PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_PATH}/mysql-connector/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp src/*.h)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} main.cpp)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        libmysqlcppconn
        OpenSSL::SSL
        OpenSSL::Crypto
        ${CONAN_LIBS}
)
```

Further info:

```
openssl@3: stable 3.1.0 [keg-only] (via homebrew)
   - keg only so I added 
           export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
           export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
           export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"
     to my .zshrc as homebrew suggested this

cmake: stable 3.26.0
mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.13
Additional packages installed by conan:
    libcurl/7.87.0
    cpr/1.10.0
    boost/1.81.0
    nlohmann_json/3.11.2

OSX Ventura 13.1
```

I am currently at my witts ends with this problem and hope someone know what the problem here might be.

Comment: Have you tried to link with crypto library, as suggested in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858965/3440745)? (`OpenSSL::Crypto` is not the same as `crypto`).

Comment: "As I understand this means that the the program couldnt link some headers found in the openSSL library" - No, the errors are about functions, used in `libmysqlcppconn-static.a` library. OpenSSL uses that library, but since it is a **static** library, linkage with it doesn't resolve those symbols.

Comment: Importing `crypto` solved most of the undefined symbols, thank you very much. The last remaining message is an undefined symbol `"_SSL_get_peer_certificate", referenced from: ssl_verify_server_cert(Vio*, char const*, char const**)`

Answer (score 0):

Use connector 8.0.

It has 2 different APIs, and the JDBC one is what your program expects.

OpenSSL 3.0 has a different API, and that's why connector 1.x doesn't work.

PS: use the connector to your system, since it is linked against system openssl.

Comment: Using connector 8.0 results in the "same" linking errors + a few more missing headers (https://pastebin.com/u4S9f6YE). Also what exactly do you mean by "use the connector to your system"? (OSX Ventura 13.1)

Comment: If you look on the connector package, inside INFO_BIN you will see which versions were used to build connector:

MySQL Connector/C++ Build Information

build-date           :  2022-12-09
os-info              :  Darwin-22.1.0
compiler             :  AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
protobuf-version     :  3.6.1
build-type           :  Release
ssl-library          :  OpenSSL 1.1.1s
macos-version        :  13.0.1
mysql-version        :  8.0.32

So, using static, you need to use the same.